# Set value in 2D array fom keyboard

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm working in this code for setting values in a specific part of a [5,5] 2D array from keyboard, for example ad an "x" in column 2 row 3, and it's almost done but I keep getting an error. Let´s begin with the part of the code I have problems with:

```
int[,] data = new int[5, 5]; 

public void cargar()
{
   string[] input = Console.ReadLine().Split('=');
   string[] coordinates = input[0].Split(',');
   int[] intCoordinates = coordinates.Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToArray();
   data[intCoordinates[0]][intCoordinates[1]] = int.Parse(input[1]);  
}
```

The message refers to the 10th line, it´s about "data" (it´s the name of the array):

> "Incorrect index number inside []. 2 was expected".

It´s translated from Spanish, so I think that's what is says. How could I fix this?

Comment: your code does not show how `data` is instantiated.

Comment: Let me add it, edit on its way

Comment: Try to add comma in 10th line between your indexes: data[intCoordinates[0], intCoordinates[1]] = int.Parse(input[1]);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using a multidimensional array ([,]) but then trying to access it like its an array of arrays ([][]) - also called jagged arrays.

You need to access it like `data[intCoordinates[0],intCoordinates[1]]` instead.

The error message is telling you that you're only using one indexer when it is expecting two of them.

See [this MSDN article on multidimensional arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx), [this one on jagged arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx) and this [StackOverflow question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597720/what-are-the-differences-between-a-multidimensional-array-and-an-array-of-arrays).

Comment: Yay! That´s correct, it just got fixed, thank you XD.

Comment: No problem. Glad to assist.

Comment: People, the code appears to work just fine, but when trying to type in any value I get the IndexOutOfRangeException, even when it´s 1. Why is that?